# Is there an equivalent for firefox AddonInstall in chrome extensions?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

In Firefox [this code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager) can install a new addon:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");  

AddonManager.getInstallForURL("http://www.foo.com/test.xpi", function(aInstall) {  
  // aInstall is an instance of {{AMInterface("AddonInstall")}}  
  aInstall.install();  
}, "application/x-xpinstall");
```

I used it for a custom updater and works very well. Now I was wondering if **is there something similar for Chrome extensions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`chrome.management` API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html) - it has all kinds of extension manipulation functions with the notable exception of extension installation. This is definitely intentional, Chrome developers don't want to allow writing "custom updaters" (something that could be easily misused).

There is only a limited solution to install extensions via [`chrome.webstore.install()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webstore.html) - you get the same "service" as any website. You have to add a `<link>` tag to your background page like this:

```html
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/..." />
```

You can call `chrome.webstore.install()` then and the user will be presented with a confirmation prompt. Installing extensions not present in the Web Store isn't possible, same goes for silent installations.